# Is Stack Exchange using MiniProfiler for every request?

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler, stackexchange

If so, how does Stack Exchange storage those data(SQL, NoSQL?).

PS: I'm planning to use MiniProfiler for every request (and using MiniProfiler.EF6). I'm planning to implementation IStorage.Save like :

1. add MiniProfiler data to a ConcurrentQueue.
2. In another thread batch loading data, serializing those data to
   JSON, then gzip the JSON string. (since those data cotains many SQL
   query)
3. send the gzip result to a MessageQueue

Comment: You might have better success asking at meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on meta